# Laravel - Callable returning blank screen

Tags: php, laravel, controller, closures

I'm trying to create a callback to return my views based on data from my current logged-in user. If I do something basic like echoing 'hi' it works, is there any way accomplish this?

```
function checkUser($type,$callback){
  if( is_callable($callback) ){
    call_user_func($callback);
  }
}
class FichaController extends Controller
{
   public function contarFichas()
     {
        checkUser('particular',function(){
            $currentUser = Auth::user();
            $countFichas = Ficha::where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->count();
            return view('particular.index', array('countFichas' => $countFichas));
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: what does checkUser return?noting

Comment: @madalinivascu if I change checkUser to:

    function checkUser($type,$callback){
      if( is_callable($callback) ){
        echo 'hi';
      }
    }

it works (it echoes 'hi').

Answer (score 0):

Return the result from checkUser

```
 if( is_callable($callback) ){
    return $callback();
  }


public function contarFichas()
     {
        return checkUser('particular',function(){
            $currentUser = Auth::user();
            $countFichas = Ficha::where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->count();
            return view('particular.index', array('countFichas' => $countFichas));
        });
     }
```

Comment: Blank screen again.

Comment: why do you need a function with a callback?

Comment: I'm trying to call a view depending on the value provided as the `$type` parameter. For example: `checkUser('particular',function(){})` would call `view1.blade.php` while  `checkUser('xyz',function(){})` would call `view2.blade.php` (for as many views as I want).